# Stanford Javascript Crypto Library. (SJCL) encrypt and decrypt without sending parameters

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, sjcl

In the [SJCL Demo](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/demo/) there is the checkbox "Send the parameters and authenticated data along with the message." to reduce the message to a very short string.

I can´t find a list with valid parameters for the use in the encrypt (and decrypt) function:

```
var encryptedMessage = sjcl.encrypt(key,message, ??? );

var decryptedMessage = sjcl.decrypt(key,encryptedMessage);
```

Comment: There are quite a lot of possible options: http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/src/core_convenience.js.html

Comment: When the checkbox is selected necessary parameters wil be sent along with the message such as the iv and password salt. If the receiver already knows these they don't need to be sent.

Comment: The options are listed [here](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/wiki/Symmetric-Crypto), which ones do you have trouble with? The encryption options are included in the "encryptedMessage" which is kind of a container format, so you don't need to specify them during decryption. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Note that this is kind of stupidity (not the first stupidity of SJCL) because it lets the attacker fill in the options, e.g a smaller authentication tag. You'd better check the variables yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter a password, text and click encrypt the result will be in the Ciphertext box, ex:
password:"pass", message:"text", Authenticated data:" xxx"

Result:

```
{
"iv":"tjp81jkAzUpW1bI9gLDDpg==", // iv Base64 encoded
"v":1,                           // version
"iter":1000,                     // iteration count
"ks":128,                        // key size in bits
"ts":64,                         // authentication strength
"mode":"ccm",                    // mode
"adata":"xxx",                   // authenticated data
"cipher":"aes",                  // cipher
"salt":"lx06UoJDNys=",           // key derivation salt
"ct":"Gv7ptKdTtUz6AGtX"          // ciphet text
}
```

Example usage from the [site](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/):

```
sjcl.encrypt("password", "data") 
sjcl.decrypt("password", "encrypted-data")
```

The catch is that notwithstanding the availability stated the modes `CCM` and    `OCB2` are not commonly supported across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks for your help!!!** For a minimal message overhead in my database this solution works for me:

```
  //Encrypt
  var encryptedMessage = sjcl.encrypt("myPassword","myMessage",{mode:"ccm",iter:1000,ks:128,ts:64,v:1,cipher:"aes",adata:"",salt:"myGeneratedSalt"});
  var parsedMessage = JSON.parse(encryptedMessage);
  delete parsedMessage.mode;
  delete parsedMessage.iter;
  delete parsedMessage.ks;
  delete parsedMessage.ts;
  delete parsedMessage.v;
  delete parsedMessage.cipher;
  delete parsedMessage.salt;
  delete parsedMessage.adata;
  encryptedMessageWithoutParameters = JSON.stringify(parsedMessage);

  //Decrypt
  var parsedMessage = JSON.parse(encryptedMessageWithoutParameters);
  jQuery.extend(parsedMessage,{mode:"ccm",iter:1000,ks:128,ts:64,v:1,cipher:"aes",adata:"",salt:"myGeneratedSalt"});
  messageWithParameters = JSON.stringify(parsedMessage);
  var decryptedMessage = sjcl.decrypt("myPassword",messageWithParameters);

  //Result > "myMessage"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sjcl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var cypheredMsg = sjcl.encrypt("secret", "Hi Amresh!");
    var plainMsg = sjcl.decrypt("secret", cypheredMsg);

    console.log(cypheredMsg);
    console.log(plainMsg);

    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, Steffen.  It might be a little cleaner to separate the options, so then we can iterate through the options to delete.  Also, the salt needs to be base64, which we can easily generate with JavaScript's btoa() function.

```
  //Encrypt
  var salt = btoa( "myGeneratedSalt" );
  var options = {mode:"ccm",iter:1000,ks:128,ts:64,v:1,cipher:"aes",adata:"",salt:salt}
  var encryptedMessage = sjcl.encrypt("myPassword","myMessage",options);
  var parsedMessage = JSON.parse(encryptedMessage);
  var prop;
  for (prop in options) {
    delete parsedMessage[prop];
  }
  encryptedMessageWithoutParameters = JSON.stringify(parsedMessage);

  //Decrypt
  var parsedMessage = JSON.parse(encryptedMessageWithoutParameters);
  jQuery.extend(parsedMessage,options);
  messageWithParameters = JSON.stringify(parsedMessage);
  var decryptedMessage = sjcl.decrypt("myPassword",messageWithParameters);

  //Result > "myMessage"
```